# Evaluating a greatest integer function limit

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to3^-}([x]^2-9)/(x^2-9)$$

From what I understand you cannot factor them and then cancel like expressions because of the greatest integer brackets. $([x]-3)/(x-3)$ does not simplify.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Note that $[x]^2 =4$ for $x$ close to $3$ satisfying $x<3$.